# Same record appearing in every result of query using NHibernate and C#

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

If I execute the following T-SQL query

```
select * from irmInterface.dbo.IRM_TEMP_Appointment_archive where PatientNumber in
(
'2614897'
)
```

I get 5 different records.

When I run the following query in C#

```
var query = session.QueryOver<IRM_TEMP_Appointment_archive>()
     .Where(a => (a.PatientNumber == MRN))
     .List()
     .ToList<IRM_TEMP_Appointment_archive>();
```

I get the correct number of results (5) but the same record is copied into each item in the result set.

Why?